# Trying to get property 'groupid' of non-object (View: /home/codename/AIM/resources/views/home/search.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

There is a link in menu bar named organizations when I click on it,I am getting this error and url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?query=&group=2. I got the value of groupid by using echo.I am also getting the all country name from my db.

HomeController.php

```
public function userSearch(Request $request) {
        $group_id = $request->get('group');
        $users = [];
        if($request->has('group')) {
            if($request->get('group') == 1) {
                $companies = EntrepreneurCompanies::get();
                $ids = [];
                foreach ($companies as $company) {
                    $cat = explode(",",$company->category);
                    if(in_array($request->get('query'),$cat)) {
                        $ids[] = $company->created_by;
                    }
                }
                $users = Entrepreneurs::whereIn('created_by',$ids)->get();
            }
            elseif ($request->get('group') == 2) {
                $users = Organization::get();
                if($request->get('query') != "") {
                    $ids = [];
                    foreach ($users as $company) {
                        $cat = explode(",",$company->categories);
                        if(in_array($request->get('query'),$cat)) {
                            $ids[] = $company->created_by;
                        }
                    }
                    $users = Organization::whereIn('created_by',$ids)->get();
                }
            }
             else {
            $users = Entrepreneurs::where('country',$request->get('country'))->get();
            $users = collect($users)->merge(Organization::where('country',$request->get('country'))->get());
            $users = collect($users)->merge(Supporter::where('country_interest','LIKE','%'.$request->get('country'). '%')->get());
            $users = collect($users)->merge(Investor::where('country_interest','LIKE','%'.$request->get('country'). '%')->get());
        }
        return view('home.search',compact('group_id','users'));
    }
}
```

search.blade.php

```
    <section class="list-items ddd">
        @if(count((array)$users) > 0)
            @foreach($users as $key => $user)
                @php
                    $group_id = $user->user->groupid;
                    $company = null;
                @endphp
           @endforeach
        @endif
</section>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/search','HomeController@userSearch');
```

Comment: What is `$user->user` meant to be?

Comment: This is an object.

Comment: The error message is telling you that it is _not_ an object. Use `dd($user->user);` or `dump($user->user);`

Comment: using dump($user->user),App\Models\UserDetails {#821 ▼
  #table: "userdetails"
  #fillable: array:5 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:18 [▶]
  #original: array:18 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}

Comment: One of the `$user->user` in the loop isn't an object according to the error. Just because the first iteration doesn't throw an error doesn't mean that they all wont.

Comment: Here, there are many countries this is working for all except when I select India this error come up.